# How does clustering happen over RED,GREEN AND BLUE Channels for dominant color extraction using KMeans

Tags: image, opencv, scikit-learn, k-means, image-segmentation

I have a rgb image of dimensions (500,500,3). I am trying to extract let's say k dominant colors from it(for the purpose of understanding Lets assume k to be 4). I have reshaped the image to (500*500,3) to pass it to the sklearn kmeans classifier.

Does the classifier make clusters on red,green and blue channel separately?
And if it does-
lets say the cluster are formed at intensities
40,80,90,135 for red
60,90,130,240 for green
20,40,60,90 for blue.

how does the classifier decide which  cluster center of one color to map with what cluster center of the other?

Comment: clustering in 3D space

Answer (score 1):

Clustering is done in the following procedure:

- Let's say k = 3. Pick 3 different random colors in the image.
- Calculate the difference between these points and all pixels. The difference in RGB image is `((R - R') + (G - G') + (B - B')) / 3`.
- Assign each pixel a label based on the difference found. That means, every pixel is assigned to the cluster where its difference is minimum.
- Now, we have all the pixels labeled. Calculate the mean value of each cluster and repeat the procedure until there is no change. That means in each step, find the difference of all pixels between cluster means, and assign new labels based on the minimum distance and calculate new mean values.

So, the clustering is not done on RGB channels seperately, but the difference function plays the key role here.